# Text Repeater in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm just learning Android and doing a simple Text Repeater app. I have a problem now.

I have this code

```
package eu.make4u.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_input, et_output, et_number;
    Button b_go;

    String text ="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input);
        et_output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_output);
        et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
        b_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_go);

        b_go.setOnClickListener(new.View.OnClickListener()) {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v){
                String input = et_input.getText().toString();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(et_number.getText().toString());

                for (int i=0; i < number; i++){
                    text = text + input + " ";
                }
                et_output.setText(text);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I have 5 errors

[image: 5 error in android studio]

I'm going through this course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trMTw1rx30I

I can not find any mistakes, could anyone help me?

Comment: In `b_go.setOnClickListener(new.View.OnClickListener())` First change new. to new without the dot, new is not a Class / Object its a keyword

Comment: I think there is another error: if you are trying to convert like this String to integer it will be an error, because you can cast empty string to integer. You should handle it.

Comment: Try to click on the error <identifier> and look which line is it pointing and reply back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some bracket related syntax issue. Fixed:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_input, et_output, et_number;
    Button b_go;

    String text ="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input);
        et_output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_output);
        et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
        b_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_go);

        b_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //you had an extra bracket here
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v){
                String input = et_input.getText().toString();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(et_number.getText().toString());

                for (int i=0; i < number; i++){
                    text = text + input + " ";
                }
                et_output.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_input;
private EditText et_output;
private EditText et_number;

private Button b_go;

private String text = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initView();
    setListener();
}

private void setListener() {

    b_go.setOnClickListener(new GoButtonOnclickListener());
}

private void initView() {
    et_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input);
    et_output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_output);
    et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
    b_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_go);
}

private class GoButtonOnclickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String input = et_input.getText().toString();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(et_number.getText().toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            text = text + input + " ";
        }
        et_output.setText(text);
    }
}
```

}

**Note:-**  Always remember whenever you want to perform on Click event so you have to follow standard coding format, i have done this in code.Please check that. It will improve your code habits. :)